# Getting (os error 3) The system cannot find the path specified when trying to build a staking pool

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, staking

So I'm following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbmA6GLDEFk, and trying to build a demo staking pool using the scripts at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/stake-pool/cli. When I'm running `./setup-stake-pool.sh 15` I'm getting the error `error: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. The easiest might be to manually omit the keypair files passed in, since they can be generated by the CLI, so your command becomes:

```
$ spl-stake-pool create-pool --epoch-fee-numerator 1 --epoch-fee-denominator 100 --withdrawal-fee-numerator 2 --withdrawal-fee-denominator 100 --deposit-fee-numerator 3 --deposit-fee-denominator 100 --referral-fee 0 --max-validators 2350
```

Otherwise, there may be an issue with your CLI setup, you can check that with:

```
$ solana config get
Config File: /home/me/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /home/me/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

Make sure that the config file and default keypair path are there and configured.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This image is from setup-test-validator .Try running setup-test-validator , add-validators , deposit scripts before .
You have to generate keypairs for accounts and then you could run setup-stake-pool

This error is because the .json keypair file is not created yet inside keys directory

Comment: There is a keys folder with all the .json files of the keypairs ( of the validator accounts got by running ```./setup-local-validators.sh```) as well as mint.json, reserve.json and stake-pool.json. Yet trying to run the setup-stake-pool.sh file gives the same error.